# How to use HTTP authentication with RCurl

Tags: r, soap, wsdl, rcurl

I want to setup a small R script requesting data from a SOAP/WSDL web service using RCurl's `CurlPerform` function. Remote Server requires HTTP authentication.

What I found is that RCurl's `getURL` function (e.g., `getURL("https://api.picloud.com/job/?jids=12", userpwd="key:secret", httpauth = 1L)`) could maybe used for authentication purposes.

Using `getURL` delivers a valid server/web service/WSDL reply; i.e., authentication seems to work.

However, I then want to fetch data from the web service with RCurl's `CurlPerform` function. How Do I use HTTP authentication alongside with `CurlPerform`?

Here is the code of the R script:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

#####################

headerfields = c(
  Accept = "text/xml",
  Accept = "multipart/*",
  SOAPAction = "http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/hwims/webservices/spurwerte-ws?wsdl",
  'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
)

#####################

body = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:spur='http://spurwerte.webservice.hwims.t_systems_mms.com/' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<soapenv:Body>
<spur:liefereWerteZuSpur2>
<spurIdentifikator>
<messstationKennziffer>501060</messstationKennziffer>
<messstationTyp>Pegel</messstationTyp>
<physikalischeGroesse>W</physikalischeGroesse>
<spurTyp>Ziel</spurTyp>
</spurIdentifikator>
<startZeitpunkt>2019-05-01T00:00:00</startZeitpunkt>
<endeZeitpunkt>2019-05-02T00:00:00</endeZeitpunkt>
<statistischeZeitangaben>true</statistischeZeitangaben>
</spur:liefereWerteZuSpur2>
</soapenv:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"

#####################

reader = basicTextGatherer()

getURL("http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/hwims/webservices/spurwerte-ws?wsdl", userpwd="usr:pwd", httpauth = 1L)

curlPerform(
url = "http://www.umwelt.sachsen.de/umwelt/infosysteme/hwims/webservices/spurwerte-ws?wsdl",
httpheader = headerfields,
postfields = body,
writefunction = reader$update,
verbose = TRUE
)

xml <- reader$value()
xml
```

Seems like authentication via `getURL` is working but `CurlPerform` delivers a non-authenticated request. Server answeres with: "This request requires HTTP authentication"

N.B.: Actual user name and password were replaced in the code above.